# Message Retry and adding poison message to DLQ in Spring JMS And ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a requirement to load messages from two queues and i am using ActiveMQ I have to implement the Retry mechanism in case of any error or network or application server failure and load back into the same Queue. Also, I want to load any poison messages to DLQ.

Please let me know if I can acheive these through Spring JMS. Also, please advise some good examples to accomplish this task. I checked Spring JMS documentation and have not much details in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broker function with ActiveMQ - just configure the broker with the appropriate policies.

If using a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, you must use transacted sessions; then, if the listener throws an exception the message will be rolled back onto the queue and the broker's retry/DLQ policies kick in.

See [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) about enabling transactions.

Comment: Gary, can you please take a look at my code and advise.